# Git: add branch created in forked repo to original repo

Tags: git

I forked a repo `A` to create repo `B`, created a new branch (let's call it `b_branch`) and committed a few changes to that branch. I'd now like to add that branch and my changes to repo `A` under the same branch name (e.g. `b_branch`). How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using a git hosting tool like github, gitlab, etc? Or do you control both repos?

Comment: I'm using GitHub, but I figured this could be done via pure git

Comment: I have write access to both repos, yes

Comment: Push to main repo

Comment: If you're using github, [why not make a pull-request](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I can only see how to make a pull request to existing branches in A. Is there a way to create a PR for a simultaneous new branch?

Comment: What do you mean? The target branch in the original repo should be which ever branch you'd like to merge into.

Comment: I don't want to merge into an existing branch in the original repo. I want to create a new branch in the original repo

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer ah. Then yeah, use Dmitry’s answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have write access to A repo, you can do

```sh
git remote add A <url of repo A>

git push A branch_b
```